# Powershell/Win32-Openssh ssh connection through java fails

Tags: ssh, openssl, powershell-2.0, ssh-keys, openssh

I am trying to move from an old ssh server (based on free ssh) to the new Powershell/Win32-Openssh server. I have download the latest tested version, but i am having some problems between the client and the server. First some test I have done:

- Tested from the windows console: Works ok.
- Tested through the application against the Powershell/Win32-Openssh server: fails.
- Tested through the application against the old ssh server: Works.

Have anyone had this problem or have an insight on how to solve it?

Environment:

- Server side: Windows 2008 r2
- Client Side: Windows 7 64 bits
- Java Aplication using "JSch - Java Secure Channel" to create an ssh channel.
- Sshd version: Win32-OpenSSH (4_5_2016)

---

```
Client Log (jsch java logs):
2016-05-04 14:38:26,081 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: Connecting to 10.73.28.31 port 22201
2016-05-04 14:38:26,081 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: Connection established
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1p1 Microsoft_Win32_port_with_VS
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: aes256-ctr is not available.
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: aes192-ctr is not available.
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: aes256-cbc is not available.
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: aes192-cbc is not available.
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: arcfour256 is not available.
2016-05-04 14:38:26,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: 
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server: 
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: none
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: none
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: 
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client: 
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
2016-05-04 14:38:26,175 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: Disconnecting from 10.73.28.31 port 22201
```

---

```
Server Logs:
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diff
ie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug3: w32_select fd:4
debug3: Total in fds:1
debug2: on_select - io:0067E0D0 type:1 rd:1
debug3: WSARecv - pio: 0067E0D0
debug2: WSARecv - WSARecv() returned 0, io:0067E0D0
debug3: wait() on 0 events and 0 childres
debug2: WSARecvCompletionCB - io:0067E0D0, pending_state:1, flags:0, error:0, received:88
debug3: select - returning 1
debug3: w32_read fd:4
debug3: recv - io:0067E0D0
debug2: recv - returning 88 bytes from prior completed IO, remaining:0, io:0067E0D0
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.73.24.24: invalid argument
debug1: do_cleanup
```

As can be seen the server expects a SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT (define with value 32) from the client. However the client is sending that exactly (2016-05-04 14:38:26,143 ERROR [stderr] (default task-69) INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent) also value 32. Dont worry about the name of the constant definition, both have a value of 32 even if the name is different (SSH2_* vs SSH_*)

I have track all the comunication and it looks ok, except for the fact that the server considers that there is a problem with the information sent by the client ....

```
Configuration file:
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.84 2011/05/23 03:30:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 22201
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
HostKey C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ServerKeyBits 2048
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG
StrictModes no
MaxSessions 1000
RSAAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
Subsystem   sftp    /win32openssh/bin/sftp-server.exe
Subsystem   scp /win32openssh/bin/scp.exe
```

Francisco

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Well, I see it more as a possible problem with the implementation of the openssh, and how to use the JSch - Java Secure Channel library. i think its not off topic

Comment: this maybe has be moved to serverfault :)